# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'resx-strings'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have created a new Sharepoint Framework project with latest generator 1.4.0 and I get this error when I try to gulp bundle or gulp serve.

when I check npm outdated I get this result:

```
Package           Current  Wanted   Latest  Location
@types/chai         3.5.2   3.5.2    4.1.2  typescript-design-patterns-03-builder
@types/react       15.6.6  15.6.6  16.0.36  typescript-design-patterns-03-builder
@types/react-dom   15.5.6  15.5.6   16.0.3  typescript-design-patterns-03-builder
ajv                 5.2.5   5.2.5    6.1.1  typescript-design-patterns-03-builder
react              15.6.2  15.6.2   16.2.0  typescript-design-patterns-03-builder
react-dom          15.6.2  15.6.2   16.2.0  typescript-design-patterns-03-builder
```

Errors are:

```
Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/SPCoreLibraryStrings.resx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'resx-strings' in 'C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib'
resolve 'resx-strings' in 'C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/lib doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/lib doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/lib doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/lib doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules
        using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/resx-strings)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules
        using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/resx-strings)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib
        using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
          using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/package.json (relative path: ./lib/resx-strings)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib
        using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
          using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./lib/resx-strings)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings is not a file
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index
                  using description file: C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/package.json (relative path: ./lib/resx-strings/index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index.json doesn't exist
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/node_modules]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/lib]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/node_modules]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/lib]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/node_modules]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/lib]
[C:/node_modules]
[C:/lib]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings.js]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings.js]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings.js]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings.js]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings.json]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings.json]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings.json]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings.json]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/node_modules/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/lib/resx-strings]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index.js]
[C:/TypescriptDesignPatterns03-Builder/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/index.json]
 @ ./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/SPCoreLibraryStrings.resx.js 5:6-29
 @ ./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/Version.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/typescriptDesignPatterns03Builder/components/TypescriptDesignPatterns03Builder.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/typescriptDesignPatterns03Builder/TypescriptDesignPatterns03BuilderWebPart.js
```